Connetcing to Amazon Aurora using DataGrip and CLEARTEXT_PLUGIN
I am trying to setup a connection using DataGrip as my IDE instead of MysqlWorkbench to connect to Amazon Aurora, so that all my connections sit in one place, though at the moment it seems impossible.
I found the following explanation on how to create such connection:

set property authenticationPlugin = com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.authentication.MysqlClearPasswordPlugin
add env variable: LIBMYSQL_ENABLE_CLEARTEXT_PLUGIN=1

But all I am getting is this error in DataGrip:

Driver class 'com.mysql.jdbc.authentication.MysqlClearPasswordPlugin' not found

The answers to this issue seems to be 5-6 years old, which makes me think they are outdated.
If anyone knows what is the correct way to setup a connection in DataGrip which includes this plugin I would be more than happy to know.
Also if there additional data that I missed to provide, do let me know.

It's hard to tell without looking at the log as the issue with missing class could have different outcomes. But I'd still suggest giving it a try.
If it doesn't work, please file an issue  https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/newIssue?project=DBE and include the idea log from Help - Show Log in Files
